# SNI visible in HTTP/3, QUIC connection?

Tags: encryption, tls, wireshark, quic

Client Hello should be encrypted in HTTP/3 and QUIC, but in Wireshark I can still see SNI of the QUIC connection when using DoH.

The names should be encrypted inside the Handshake/CRYPTO packets.

[image]
[image]

is this expected? is ECH the only way that SNI and information about the website being visited, will be encrypted?

Comment: *"Client Hello should be encrypted in HTTP/3 and QUIC"* - what information is this statement based on? See also https://quicwg.org/ops-drafts/draft-ietf-quic-manageability.html#name-server-name-indication-sni

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I saw it here:

https://www.privacyguides.org/advanced/dns-overview/?h=sni#server-name-indication-sni:~:text=Governments%2C%20in%20particular,also%20be%20encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

> Early in its development, there were considerations of the potential of QUIC to be censorship resistant. By design, QUIC protects more communication data than traditional TCP+TLS traffic. Unlike TCP-based TLS, QUIC already encrypts the initial packets of a connection. Although the keys of this initial encryption are known to observers of the connection, censors have to do the additional work of extracting the keys and decrypting the information in order to eavesdrop on the information contained in the initial packets. This makes packet inspection more complex and less efficient.

> So, while it is technically still possible to censor HTTP/3 connections based on the SNI in TLS, the collected data shows that hardly any censors actually parse and use this information (even when they do parse the SNI in traditional HTTPS traffic).

Taken from here: https://www.opentech.fund/news/a-quick-look-at-quic/

Wireshark supports reading those keys and decrypts the client hello ([code](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/2691f87ef9247e80581f9737b2cda5ba90aa7347/epan/dissectors/packet-quic.c))